# Insert saved session storage value into HTML

Tags: javascript, session-storage

How would I rewrite this so I could use the stored value inside the container div?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6B6x/4/)

```
<input id="email" type="text">
<div id="storage"></div>

<div class="container">This is some text. I want the value to show up in between the p tags here:<p></p>!</div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    var text = document.getElementById('email');
    text.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        sessionStorage.text = text.value;
        document.getElementById('storage').innerHTML = 'Your stored value is ' + sessionStorage.text;
    }, false);
}());
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? The value shows up properly when I type. Is the issue that you want it positioned between the paragraphs? You're inserting it into `#storage`. You could insert it wherever. But move `#storage` into the `p` tag, or set the `id="storage"` to your `p` tag instead of the `div`?

Comment: Yes, the function itself works, but what I want is to take it out of being dependent on innerHTML inside the JS, so that the value shows up wherever I put it in the HTML. <p id="storage"></p> doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Putting the id on the <p> element should work, as David suggested. You would have to then remove that same id from the <div> above (maybe that's why it wasn't working). Also, the way you're storing to sessionStorage is incorrect. You should use setItem and getItem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: `<p id="storage">` works, but only if you *remove* the ID from the div with that ID (since ID's must be unique in the document). If you want to insert it into both the div and the paragraph, use `class="storage"` instead, and `document.getElementsByClassName('storage')` and iterate over that. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1d1mxx7g/)

Comment: @dcochran That works. Thank you for the explanation and link.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Thank you so much!